Using on:input on an Input element in svelte I am getting a casting error
In svelte using on:input on an input element, I am trying to properly cast the type and it does work but I am getting a typescript error in the editor:

Property data does not exist on type Event & { currentTarget: EventTarget & HTMLInputElement; }. ts(2339)

on:input={(elm) => {
    if (elm.data !== null) {
        // not null
    }
}}


The event is not typed more specifically because depending on the type attribute of the element, you can get different event objects (see this issue).
You can e.g. extract the function and add a type assertion:
function onInput(e: Event) {
    const inputEvent = e as InputEvent;
    console.log(inputEvent.data);
}

<input on:input={onInput} />

(You can also add an intersection to type currentTarget as shown in the error if necessary.)

yea, just trying to understand why it required the function to be abstracted, you can't just put the function inline with the type set. Oh well, thanks.

Svelte 3/4 don't allow TS syntax in the template; Svelte 5 does, but even then, you would get a type mismatch error, so you would need to assert the type in the function body.

I amended my answer with some more info and a link to a relevant GitHub issue. (If this sufficiently answered the question, you could accept it using the checkmark outline on the side.)
